# How to listen for Audio Buttons via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

[Google Play Music](https://play.google.com/music) has a feature that I'm interested in. To demonstrate it, play a song, plug in headphones with Play-Pause control, and press the pause button. You'll notice that Play Music is controllable by this button. How do they do this? Is it a part of a more modern Web API, or are they listening to a "keyboard" press? Any information is welcome.

EDIT: To clarify, I'm specifically specifying for Chrome Desktop, in my case Windows, although it appears to work in other places. Additionally, this is not a feature of chrome or windows, as it only appears to work on that specific site

Comment: Wouldn't this work with any application playing audio, not just this site?

Comment: @BSMP is a chrome feature? I'll try on other places

Comment: @LGSon What do you mean by "read their documents"? Do they have a website or something that divulges their technological features?

Comment: Sorry...was to quick to to write that comment. It is an OS function that a software like Chrome Desktop can detect, through native code, and pass on as an event to i.e. javascript

Comment: @LGSon I can't think of a Web Interface that they might be using. Maybe it's a trick with the Web Bluetooth API, IDK

Comment: No, when push such buttons there goes a signal through the audio cable back into the device, which the device's OS/hardware detect. Based on the device it understands different signal, and therefore, when you by headsets, they are compatible with i.e. Android or iOS etc., and same principle for a computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are doing it through their extension [Google Play Music](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-play-music/icppfcnhkcmnfdhfhphakoifcfokfdhg). It doesn't seem like it's a Web API or anything standardized. Try disabling it, it should stop working.